# How to make a video play correctly on any computer?

Tags: video, codec

Does anyone know how can i see what codecs a video files is using? I need to run a video on a friend computer but i don't know if he has the same codecs as I do. How you will solve this problem?

ps: The computers are running Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a single file you didn't create, GSpot will tell you what codecs are required.

If you're creating the file; the most common codecs/containers available on any computer are WMV, or QuickTime (usually an H.264). A WMV will require Windows Media Player or Flip4Mac installed if using a Mac, while QuickTime would require QuickTime or QuickTime Alternative to be installed on the PC.

Answer (score 4):

When I want to do something like this I just recommend [VLC Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/vlc_portable) and don't worry about codecs since it plays most everything. If I'm taking along the video, I have VLC Portable on the same flash drive. If I'm not in the same place at the same time I give the friend a quick introduction to it and have them "Install" it. If they don't like it all they have to do is delete the dir. Most everyone I run into ends up doing a normal install.

Answer (score 3):

[GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) is your friend.